# Exchange Online: How to get ManagedBy attribute by alias and not Display Name

Tags: exchange-server

I have a script that syncs distribution list owners. Unfortunately when querying a list, the managedby comes back as display names. Display names are *not* unique, and the business isn't willing to make them so. As such, I cannot tell which "John Doe" is jdoe and jdoe_a2afe. Is there any way to query either via graph or exchange powershell cmdlets to get the managedby owners of an Exchange Distribution Group in a format other than Display Name?

Answer (score 0):

Following script can export email addresses of all "managed" by field as a csv file

```
$Admins=(Get-DistributionGroup | Select-object -ExpandProperty ManagedBy)
$results = foreach ($Admin in $Admins)

{$mailbox=(Get-Mailbox -Identity $Admin).PrimarySmtpAddress
$mailbox>>C:\Report\Report.csv
}
```

Hope, this help to create your own version

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Thank you but no it doesn't, like I said I need to disambiguate two owners who both have the Display Name "John Doe", and your script doesn't do that, it would just return two smtp addresses but not clear which is which, therefore provides me no value when I need to compare if one or the other has already been added as an owner.